# Google Drive API - oAuth 2 - downloading file - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I am trying to download a file from my google drive using Google Drive API and its PHP library, however I am stucked in retrieving the file content.

```
/*
 * Initialize Google Client
 */
$client = new \Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setScopes(array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'));

/*
 * Set access token (yes, it's valid)
 */
$client->setAccessToken(ACCESS_TOKEN);

$service = new \Google_Service_Drive($client);

/*
 * Find the certain file
 */
foreach ($service->files->listFiles()->getItems() as $item) {
    /**
     * @var \Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile $item
     */

    if ($item->getTitle() == 'test.txt') {
        $sUrl = $item->getDownloadUrl();

        /*
         * Do a request
         */
        $request = new \Google_Http_Request($sUrl, 'GET', null, null);
        $httpRequest = $client->getIo()->executeRequest($request);

        if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
            echo $httpRequest->getResponseBody();

            exit();
        } else {
            /*
             * Something went wrong
             */
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing to notice is that Google_IO_Abstract::executeRequest(Google_Http_Request) should return Google_Http_Request (according to class documentation and Google's example https://developers.google.com/drive/web/examples/php), however id does not. It returns this associative array

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  bool(false)
  [1]=>
  array(12) {
    ["access-control-allow-origin"]=>
    string(1) "*"
    ["access-control-allow-credentials"]=>
    string(5) "false"
    ["access-control-allow-headers"]=>
    string(1000) "Accept, Accept-Language, Authorization, Cache-Control, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Type, Date, GData-Version, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Unmodified-Since, Origin, OriginToken, Pragma, Range, Slug, Transfer-Encoding, X-ClientDetails, X-GData-Client, X-GData-Key, X-Goog-AuthUser, X-Goog-PageId, X-Goog-Encode-Response-If-Executable, X-Goog-Correlation-Id, X-Goog-Request-Info, X-Goog-Experiments, x-goog-iam-role, x-goog-iam-authorization-token, X-Goog-Spatula, X-Goog-Upload-Command, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Disposition, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Length, X-Goog-Upload-Content-Type, X-Goog-Upload-File-Name, X-Goog-Upload-Offset, X-Goog-Upload-Protocol, X-Goog-Visitor-Id, X-HTTP-Method-Override, X-JavaScript-User-Agent, X-Pan-Versionid, X-Origin, X-Referer, X-Upload-Content-Length, X-Upload-Content-Type, X-Use-HTTP-Status-Code-Override, X-YouTube-VVT, X-YouTube-Page-CL, X-YouTube-Page-Timestamp"
    ["access-control-allow-methods"]=>
    string(11) "GET,OPTIONS"
    ["www-authenticate"]=>
    string(50) "GoogleLogin realm="http://www.google.com/accounts""
    ["date"]=>
    string(29) "Wed, 24 Dec 2014 11:23:16 GMT"
    ["expires"]=>
    string(29) "Wed, 24 Dec 2014 11:23:16 GMT"
    ["cache-control"]=>
    string(18) "private, max-age=0"
    ["server"]=>
    string(59) "UploadServer ("Built on Dec 19 2014 10:24:45 (1419013485)")"
    ["content-length"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["content-type"]=>
    string(24) "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    ["alternate-protocol"]=>
    string(15) "443:quic,p=0.02"
  }
  [2]=>
  int(401)
}
```

From this array we can see that content-length is 0, which indicates that something went wrong.

If I call the file's download URL directly form browser, it returns me 401 Unauthorised error, which is probably correct as the request from my browser is not authorised, however it means that the file really exist, the download URL is correct and I should be able to download it through API.

Any suggestions how can I access the content of file?

Comment: Did you make it work? I'll greatly appreciate if you post a valid source code back. As described below, the documentation API is completely outdated...

Comment: Yes, I did, I'll post solution as soon as I can. And yes, it was because of outdated Google documentation and outdated sources on GitHub ..

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation which you refer:

> The file content is retrieved using the *$client->getIo()->**authenticatedRequest*** helper method of the PHP client library

Notice it's an Authenticated Request. Maybe is your problem, hope it helps.

---

**Edit:**

The documentation must be outdated. The `authenticatedRequest` is in `Google_Auth_Abstract` class, not in `Google_IO_Abstract`. I think the code should be:

```
$client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is no "authenticatedRequest()" method in Google_IO_Abstract class ( https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/IO/Abstract.php )

Comment: @user10099 You're right. I [searched for](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=authenticatedRequest) and updated the answer for what I believe is the correct code. I hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this.

First of all you need to login to developer console in Google.
Go to **APIs & auth** -> **Credentials**
and make sure you have a  Service Account. If you don't have one, click on **Create new Client ID** -> **Service account**.

There you'll receive a P12 file and an email.

Now, back to the code.

```
    $downloadURL = $item->getDownloadUrl();
    $key = file_get_contents("WHERE YOUR GOOGLE KEY FILE IS.p12");
    if (!$key)
        return null;
    $email = "WHAT IS THE EMAIL PROVIDED BY GOOGLE";
    $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials($email, array(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE), $key);
    $this->client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);
    $cred->sub = $email;

    $request = new Google_Http_Request($downloadURL, 'GET', null, null);
    $httpRequest = $this->client->getAuth()->authenticatedRequest($request);
    if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
...
```

The rest as usual.